# Doing Excel calculation between sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Is is possible to do calulation on Sheet2 collecting numbers from sheet1?
The reason im asking, I have a *.csv who i import to a excel document. (sheet1)
When i do the calculation in sheet 2 i get "#value!" If i do the calculation`=((Sheet1!G1+Sheet1!H1)-(Sheet1!C1+Sheet1!D1))*24`

Example Sheet1(data from csv)

```
A1        B1       C1         D1    E1         F1    G1         H1
546545656 Stianbla 31.08.2015 17:36 31.08.2015 17:36 31.08.2015 17:36
```

Example Sheet2

```
A1          B1        C1         D1         E1         F1         G1         H1    
=SHEET1!A1 =SHEET1!B1 =SHEET1!C3 =SHEET1!D1 =SHEET1!E1 =SHEET1!F1 =SHEET1!G1 =SHEET1!H1
```

Comment: `(Sheet1!G1+Sheet1!H1)` and `(Sheet1!C1+Sheet1!D1)` probably give you an error because you're trying to add a time (H1) to a date (G1), which are in two different formats.   As @kyle points out below, `31.08.2015` may not even count as a "date" in any format. :)  If you add `=((G1+H1)-(C1+D1))*24` to a cell on Sheet1, does it display what you expect, or do you still get a `#VALUE!` error?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Dates and times are stored in exactly the same manner in Excel. The problem is that Excel does not recognize values like "31.08.2015" as a date.

Comment: @Kyle that's a good point. :)

Comment: If I do the clean calc  on the same sheet it works. but I can see the format change.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Excel does not recognize values like `31.08.2015` as a date. You can force the dates into the correct format like this:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(Sheet1!G1,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(Sheet1!G1,2)&"/"&RIGHT(Sheet1!G1,4))
```

Making your entire formula look like this:

```
=((DATEVALUE(MID(Sheet1!G1,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(Sheet1!G1,2)&"/"&RIGHT(Sheet1!G1,4))+Sheet1!H1)-(DATEVALUE(MID(Sheet1!C1,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(Sheet1!C1,2)&"/"&RIGHT(Sheet1!C1,4))+Sheet1!D1))*24
```

Comment: Is it a more recognized way to save the date?  So the code can be more simple? I can edit the input data in csv  example `dd/mm/yyyy` ?

Comment: @StianStørstfeskarAndersen Try mm/dd/yyyy. I'm actually not sure if it differs by region.